# Is there a word for the sound that is made after taking a sip of hot coffee/tea?

Tags: word-choice

Sometimes, after people take a sip of hot coffee or tea and send it down their throat, they make this sound originating from the front of their mouth. Something like "Aaah" — exhaling a little steam. Usually to express delight in the deliciousness of the drink. Is there a word for this sound?

For example:

> He took a slurp from his coffee and ____ in delight.

What could go in the blank?

Comment: I think the sound varies by culture. I've heard a "ssss" sound too, an inhalation of breath through the mouth past the tongue.

Comment: I thought the sound was 'ow' because you just burnt your tongue.

Comment: Well, my description of the sound was less than good but what I meant was mostly a sigh of satisfaction.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Although it is usually used in a less positive manner, you could say that the person is letting out a [sigh](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/sigh):

> to let out one's breath audibly, as from sorrow, weariness, or relief.

Comment: 'sigh of satisfaction' <-- very good :)

Comment: "a contented sigh" ?

Answer (score 2):

The only word I know that would describe the sound is *slurp*. If you wanted to use that, you’d have to find another word to use instead of the *slurp* you’ve already got. Perhaps *He took a sip from his coffee and slurped in delight.*

Comment: No. Slurping and sipping are mutually exclusive. And the questioner is asking about the *aaahh* exhalation, not the actual drinking.

Comment: Slurping is the sound of liquid entering your mouth.

Answer (score 2):

You mean the *aaaah* sound?

A modernist might write:

> He took a slurp from his coffee and *ahhed* in delight.

Answer (score -6):

Gargle. The sound in the throat after "ahhh" is gargling.  Same as one makes when gargling mouthwash.  After coffee one would dry gargle after expression of "ahhh".   With mouthwash one would wet gargle.